# Range slider not sorting when mouse up or down action?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a range slider like this:
[image: Range Slider]

My problem is when clicking the slider and going up or down and then releasing the click, the price sort is not working.

I don't know how can ı solve this problem?

JS:

```
$(function() {

 var currencyIso = $("main").data('currency-iso-code');

 $( "#slider-range-price" ).slider({
    range:true,
    min: sliderMinValue,
    max: sliderMaxValue,
    title: "dfsdf",
    values: [ minSelectedValue, maxSelectedValue ],
    slide: function( event, ui ) {
       $( "#range-price" ).val( currencyIso + " " + ui.values[ 0 ]+".00" + " - "+ currencyIso +" " + ui.values[ 1 ] +".00" );
        min =  ui.values[ 0 ];
        max =  ui.values[ 1 ];
        $("#amountMin").val(min);
        $("#amountMax").val(max);

        $(this).children("a.ui-slider-handle").first().html('<span class="slider-left-value">' + currencyIso + '&nbsp;'+min+'.00</span>');
        $(this).children("a.ui-slider-handle").last().html('<span class="slider-right-value">' + currencyIso + '&nbsp;'+max+'.00</span>');
    }
 });

 $( "#range-price" ).val( currencyIso + " " + $( "#slider-range-price" ).slider( "values", 0 ) +".00"+" - " + currencyIso + " " + $( "#slider-range-price" ).slider( "values", 1 )+".00" ); });

$('#slider-range-price').mouseup(function() {
  var urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);;
    if(location.href.indexOf('?') != -1){
        var input = $("<input>").attr("type", "hidden").attr("name", "q").val(urlParams.get('q'));
        $('#advanceSearchFilter').append(input);
    }
  $('#advanceSearchFilter').submit(); });
```

Comment: Can you create an operational example.(Snippet)?

Comment: I think it's not possible because when sorting price its use ajax call. I think the problem is to press the slider and move up slowly it's not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [`slidestop`](https://api.jqueryui.com/slider/#event-stop) event instead of `mouseup`

```
$( "#slider-range-price" ).on( "slidestop", function( event, ui ) {} );
```